# How to patch log4j on Mac for ActiveMQ?

Tags: log4j, activemq-classic

I have got installed ActiveMQ on Mac using brew but have been identified as having a critical vulnerability related to the log4j security issue, and so it requires a patch.

In this case, how can I do patching log4j?

> /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/activemq/5.16.3/libexec/lib/optional/log4j-1.2.17.jar

> /usr/local/Cellar/activemq/5.16.3/libexec/lib/optional/log4j-1.2.17.jar

Comment: By checking which version of the application has a non-vulnerable version of it

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen ActiveMQ version is 5.16.3 and log4j version is 1.2.17

Comment: Then go to ActiveMQ website and look at which versions are vulnerable and which are not

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen when I install this 5.16.3 version was the latest version available at that time however I noticed that now 'Apache ActiveMQ 5.16.4 was released on Feb 15th, 2022. It’s an important release, switching from log4j 1.x to reload4j, and including several resolved issues and bug fixes.' Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using ActiveMQ 5.16.3 you can simply [upgrade to 5.16.4](https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-5016004-release) which replaced Log4j 1.2.17 with [Reload4j](https://reload4j.qos.ch/) 1.2.19. See [AMQ-8472](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-8472) for more details.